# Deleted bcd and now can’t boot windows

Tags: windows-10, bcd

My computer has been having problems restarting ever since I added hypervisor to my bcd so I tried to delete it but ended up deleting the entire bcd. I have tried rebuilding the bcd with `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, which returns `Total identified windows installations.
[1] D:/Windows
Add installation to boot list? Yes(Y)/No(N)/All(A):`
I type “y” and click enter but it responds with `The system cannot find the path specified.` I have tried using the automatic fix tool but it does not work. I have tried using the repair from drive feature but that didn’t work either
CPU: i7-5820k
Memory: 16GB 2400mhz

Comment: Boot into another system like Windows PE or Windows To Go, then mount the boot partition and use `bcdboot` to generate boot files again.

Comment: @iBug: Your comment worked, so it should really become an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I run into such issues (damaged or deleted BCD), I use a USB flash drive to boot into Windows PE or sometimes Windows To Go with my portable hard drive. In that environment, I mount both the system partition and boot partition, open Command Prompt and run:

```
bcdboot D:\Windows -s E:
```

Where D and E are system and boot (active partition on MBR, or ESP on GPT), respectively.

Usually that's all I do, and when I reboot the system installed on `D:` boot normally.

Comment: After trying many other things that I couldn't get working, this saved me. Cloned my Windows to a new NVMe drive and it worked fine for a day, then it wouldn't boot. I had to assign a letter to the boot partition and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: In case the ESP is not mounted automatically, you can use [mountvol](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol): `mountvol E: /s`

Comment: @Hermann Or use DiskPart: `ASSIGN LETTER E` after selecting the partition (volume).